# PDF problems with Office Web Apps 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, office-web-apps

I have problems with PDF rendering in Office Web Apps 2013.
We use Sharepoint 2013 + OWA

PDF Displays but not with all images and text. When I go to EDIT IN WORD in Office Web Apps 2013 I see those missing parts of PDF. But in any case PDF file is messed up. It does not show properly.

Is there any way to make PDF Files to show properly in Office Web Apps 2013?

I have found [this info](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Why-does-my-PDF-look-different-in-Word-1d1d2acc-afa0-46ef-891d-b76bcd83d9c8), but still is there any other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up removing PDFs from OWA completely due to the weird behavior.  Instead, they just open in the browser naturally.

```
Get-SPWOPIBinding –Application "WordPDF" | Remove-SPWOPIBinding -Confirm:$false
```